# NReco FFPMegConverter: The path is not of a legal form

Tags: c#, nreco, fody-costura

I'm using the NReco FFMPegConverter, and when I try to get a thumbnail, I get the error:

```
 System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.File.InternalGetLastWriteTimeUtc(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter.EnsureFFMpegLibs()
   at NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter.ExtractFFmpeg()
```

Here is the line of code where I'm getting my error.

```
        var filep = domainVideoFile.AbsolutePath;
        _fFMpegConverter.GetVideoThumbnail(filep, tempfileName);
```

In the above example, filep = "C:\Users\me_000\Downloads\GRoma\G.mp4"
and tempFileName = "C:\Users\me_000\Desktop\f480b6c0.jpeg"when copied directly from the Locals view in Debug mode.

There is another thread citing this issue on SO and the stated solution is to set the FFMPegToolPath property.

```
 fFMpegConverter.FFMpegToolPath = _thumbPathManager.GetFFMPegPath;
```

I've tried that and various versions of it and I still get the error. I'm using the version of 1.1.2.0 if that helps.

The error pops up no matter what I do with respect to calling FFMpegToolPath, ExtractFFmpeg and what not.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the line of code you are calling which throws that exception.

Comment: @mjwills I've made the requested edit. Sorry for leaving that piece out.

Comment: @mjwills I've figured out what the problem was and I've posted the answer if you would like to know for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very insidious but I figured out what was happening.

I'm using Fody.Costura to merge my DLL resources.  This works for all the other DLLS, but the NReco DLLs don't take kindly to being merged.  I guess somewhere along the way this is causing file pathing issues since the DLL doesn't exist as a standalone file.